# Can I factor a rational expression of the form...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-decomposition

Given two equations

$\displaystyle P_1 = \frac{1-X^2}{1-X^2}$

and

$\displaystyle P_2 = \frac{1-aX^2}{1-bX^2}$

I am told that there is a relationship between `P1` and `P2`

$P_1 \geq P_2$

It is clear that by visually comparing `P1` and `P2`, the coefficients `a` and `b` are responsible for determining the relationship between `P1` and `P2`. That being said, I would like to express the relationship

$P_1 \geq P_2$

as

$P_1 \geq P_1f(a,b)$

$1 \geq f(a,b)$

Clearly `f(a,b)` can be defined as `P2/P1`, so disregard this solution for the time being. My question is, can I express `f(a,b)` as a function of `a` and `b` alone? In other words, can I factor out `P1` from `P2` and be left with a function of `a` and `b` alone? If so, what is the form for `f(a,b)`? Is it a rational expression? Is it a transform matrix? Is it another polynomial? A convolution?

My objective is to evaluate `f(a,b)`, thus interpret the relationship between `P1` and `P2`. In other words if `f(a,b)=1` then I know `P1=P2`. I don't think I can make it any more clear.

If I can't extract an expression for `f(a,b)` as a function of `a` and `b` alone, that's fine. I'm under the impression I can't but I thought someone on here might know more than I, so I figured I would ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not say anything about the range where $a$, $b$, $x$ can be taken from. For the sake of simplicity, I will assume that $x\ne 0$, $0<1-ax^2<1$ and $0<1-bx^2<1$.

The following inequalities are equivalent to each other:
\begin{align*}
P_1 &\ge P_2 \\
\frac{1-x}{1-x} &\ge \frac{1-ax^2}{1-bx^2} \\
1 &\ge \frac{1-ax^2}{1-bx^2} \\
1-bx^2 &\ge 1-ax^2\\
ax^2 &\ge bx^2\\
a &\ge b
\end{align*}

You can do similar manipulations with $P_1>P_2$, $P_1<P_2$, $P_1=P_2$, etc.

So, for example, the function
$$f(a,b)=
  \begin{cases}
    2; & a>b, \\
    1; & a=b, \\
    0; & a<b,
  \end{cases}
$$
fulfills
\begin{align*}
f(a,b)>1 &\Leftrightarrow P_1>P-2\\
f(a,b)=1 &\Leftrightarrow P_1=P_2\\
f(a,b)<1 &\Leftrightarrow P_1<P_2
\end{align*}

---

On the other hand, if you want to have $P_1(x)=f(a,b)P_2(x)$ for every possible $x$, $a$ and $b$, this is clearly not possible, since $P_1(x)=1$ and thus the above equation gives
$$f(a,b) = \frac1{P_2(x)} = \frac{1-bx^2}{1-ax^2}$$
which clearly depends on $x$.

---

Let me say that I have tried to answer the question assuming that $a$, $b$, $x$ are numbers. As I see that you have chose tags such as [matrix-decomposition](/questions/tagged/matrix-decomposition), [matrices](/questions/tagged/matrices), [linear-algebra](/questions/tagged/linear-algebra), [linear-transformations](/questions/tagged/linear-transformations) for your question, you might have something completely different in mind. But I cannot think of any interpretation of your question which involves matrices. So I chose the only interpretation of your question which made sense to me. If it is not what you want to ask, it's up to you to clarify your question.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to provide an answer. I only tagged those thinking there might be some trick different disciplines are aware of.

Comment: Ahhh....I just realized I made P1 = 1 in my question, which probably doesn't help in terms of clarity. I'll go back and make some edits

Comment: I reverted back to the original question and accepted your answer. I'll just make a new post later if I need to

Comment: ok, I [have rolled back my answer too](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1835927/revisions), since the added information is irrelevant if the question is back to the previous form.